# Multiprocessing query in different PostgreSQL instances

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, cluster-computing

Is there any way in PostgreSQL 9.6 RC 1 to divide and process a query in two differents machines? For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN
     table2 AS t2
     ON t1.key = t2.key
```

I wanna search the table1 on the machine 1 and the table2 on the machine 2.

Assuming that I have a local network connecting the two PCs. Each one has PostgreSQL installed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "search the table"? You are not "searching" you are joining (all rows from both tables)

Comment: You can use [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) to achieve that.

Comment: Though postgres_fdw will allow you to query a remote table as though it were a local one, it will not allow "multiprocessing" -- fdw queries are still executed serially as far as I'm aware, even in 9.6. I suspect postgres_fdw is the answer to your question, as @MatheusOl suggests, but I want to clarify that based on the words you use.

Comment: That is good point @jmelesky. For "multiprocessing", you'd have to use something like [Citus](https://www.citusdata.com/) extension.